# how to make a custom shape for force field

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

There are a bunch of options for the shape of a force field like point or plane but I want to apply the force field to a custom shape, let's say a cube. The reason is:  I want hundreds of objects to be attracted to the cube to eventually FORM the cube.  Kind of like particles.  However, I don't want particles to be emitted from the shape but rather to be attracted to the shape to eventually form it.

[image: settings]

Comment: i am not totally sure but i think this is not "just a visual" shape but the working shape for the force. I assume you cannot change the visual shape for a force field.

Comment: Hello, can you please tell a bit more? Are all the objects the same? Are they agitated or do they come straight to the cube? Etc

Comment: You could put all your objects around your cube, push them away with a Turbulence,, then bake the simulation, and invert it in the Dope Sheet

Comment: The cube. You can use the surface option for the force.  The cube can also be an obstacle, this is important.  People often emit particles from a surface and then reverse frames.  There are some other options as always.  You might consider showing your work so that a potential answer does not explain things you already know.

Comment: Particles have a built in feature where the particles assume different shapes.  You can investigate this in the particle panel.  This motion may be rather linear.  This may or may not suit your goals.

Comment: You can also write a Python script to move objects/children along various curves for nonlinear motion. You should observe that isolated forces will not easily cause particles to assume the shape of some target either in some linear fashion or  without obstacles. You may want to state if linear motion is acceptable. For rather flowing curved effects, you will need multiple forces/keyframes.  Everywhere, all at once.  You may also want to show an example image/video.

Comment: you have the keyed particles that could fit your needs but you don't give enough details